# Scroll through the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, layout, scrollview

There is such a layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTV"
        tools:context=".DayTasksActivity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RWTasksOnDay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RWTasksOnDay">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/taskET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/addTaskBTN"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/add_task" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this listener:

```
addTaskBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String task = String.valueOf(taskET.getText());
        mDayLab.addTask(mDay, task);

        updateRecyclerView();
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

When you click a new item is added to the RecyclerView, you need to add ScrollView scrolled to the new items, down to the bottom. With fullScroll well, it turns out to achieve the desired result, or do something wrong.
Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: you can achieve that in recyclerview itself i.e by using scrollToPosition() or smoothScrollToPosition()

Comment: Thank you, understood. so same had to to remove ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just scroll RecyclerView ? You can scroll it to the last item with

```
your_recycler.scrollToPosition(last_item_index)
```